# $(document).ready(function()) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am technically trying to auto tab from the select element. 
This works separately like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").change(function() {
            document.getElementById(1).focus();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select name="" id="eventChoose" class="cuSelect">
        <optgroup label="Friends & Family Events">
            <option>Birthday Party</option>
            <option>Anniversary Party</option>
            <option>New Born Party</option>
            <option>Bachelors Party</option>
            <option>Kitty Party</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Corporate Party">
            <option>Team Outing</option>
            <option>Product Launch Party</option>
            <option>Recognition Party</option>
            <option>Network Event</option>
            <option>Seminars</option>
        </optgroup>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="1">
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But when i put this code in my website's main code, it stops working..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="enhanced">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="300" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,       user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="eventila-web/resources/css/styles.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#eventChoose").change(function() {
            document.getElementById(budget).focus();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    ....
```

Can somebody please tell me what the problem could be? 
I am fairly new to javascript.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? The element is not `focusing`? Any error in `console`?

Comment: If you open the console you'd probably see a `budget is not defined` error

Comment: What does `budget` variable contain in your second snippet of code?

Comment: did you just removed jquery.js reference in second code snippet?

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run. Aanchal, Stack Overflow is a *very* active place, people will jump on your question. It's best to stick around for a few minutes to answer questions, etc., after posting.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined jquery in your code. Add this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

See my comments below.  You haven't included the jQuery script and it's unclear what "budget" is.  In the code you've shown in your second example, you're probably getting a `ReferenceError` for the undefined variable `budget`. Your first code example used `1`, which works with `getElementById` but will be hard to use with a CSS selector with jQuery (you have to escape it in a non-obvious way):

```
<head>
    ...

   <!-- You didn't include jquery -->
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#eventChoose").change(function() {
            // I don't see budget defined anywhere. Is it an id? 
            $('#budget').focus();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: i had added jquery method..and budget is the id of text box i had used. Sorry i forgot to mention thst. But the problem got solved. my script function was mostly getting overrided by another function. I added my function in my main js file and removed it from the main html.

Answer (score 0):

can't use an integer as an "id".

also use the jquery method!

```
<input type="text" id="a1">

$('#a1').focus();
```

Comment: You can actually depending on DOCTYPE but it is not a good idea

Comment: `can't use an integer as an "id"` as of HTML5 you can, although they should still be referenced using a string in `getElementById()`

Comment: And in fact, even though earlier versions of HTML were more restrictive, *browsers* never were. It's still a pain to select them with CSS, though: `$("\\31").focus()` (as Rory said, better to use `getElementById` if you must use leading digits). It's fine to use a number, though (with `getElementById`), it just gets coerced to a string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

i had added jquery method..and budget is the id of text box i had used. Sorry i forgot to mention that earlier. But the problem got solved.
I had included the script in my main html file whereas i had a separate js file. So,
my script function was mostly getting overrided by another function. I added my function in my main js file and removed it from the main html. And it worked.
Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of the technique you use the id is a string and so you need to have the id in quotes.  In the second example you are using document.getElementById(budget).  This will not work because an undefined is not a valid id.  You can call document.getElementById("budget") and this will work.

Comment: Your edit corrects the statement that using an integer wouldn't work. `var budget = 1; document.getElementById(budget);` will work just fine. We have no idea what the OP is trying to do in that code. Yes, though, if `budget` is meant to be the `id` of the element, not a variable, they definitely need quotes.